# Failed to renew SSL certificate automatically

Tags: nginx, ssl, cron

I manage a Wordpress web server which uses SSL (Let's encrypt - 90 days certificate) on GCP.

To renew the SSL certificate automatically, I made a script.

```
$ cat renew-certificate.sh 
#!/bin/bash
  sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop nginx
  sudo /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/lego --tls --email="me@my-email.com" --domains="my-website.com" --domains="www.my-website.com" --path="/opt/bitnami/letsencrypt" renew --days 90
  sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start nginx
```

Then registered it in crontab to execute it every months.

```
$ sudo chmod +x /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/scripts/renew-certificate.sh
$ sudo crontab -e

0 0 1 * * /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/scripts/renew-certificate.sh >> /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/scripts/log-crontab_renew_certificate_sh-220531 2>&1
```

The crontab looks working well.
But renew-certificate.sh looks not working.

```
$ cat log-crontab_renew_certificate_sh-220531

Stopped nginx
2022/06/01 00:00:04 [INFO] [my-website.com] acme: Trying renewal with 2145 hours remaining
2022/06/01 00:00:04 [INFO] [my-website.com, www.my-website.com] acme: Obtaining bundled SAN certificate
2022/06/01 00:00:10 acme: error: 500 :: POST :: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-order :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:serverInternal :: Error creating new order
Started nginx
Stopped nginx
2022/07/01 00:00:03 Could not create client: get directory at 'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory': Get "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": EOF
Started nginx
Stopped nginx
2022/08/01 00:00:03 [INFO] [my-website.com] acme: Trying renewal with 681 hours remaining
2022/08/01 00:00:03 [INFO] [my-website.com, www.my-website.com] acme: Obtaining bundled SAN certificate
2022/08/01 00:00:11 acme: error: 500 :: POST :: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-order :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:serverInternal :: Error creating new order
Started nginx
Stopped nginx
2022/09/01 00:00:03 [INFO] [my-website.com] acme: Trying renewal with 2148 hours remaining
2022/09/01 00:00:03 [INFO] [my-website.com, www.my-website.com] acme: Obtaining bundled SAN certificate
2022/09/01 00:00:04 acme: error: 500 :: POST :: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-order :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:serverInternal :: Error creating new order
Started nginx
Stopped nginx
2022/10/01 00:00:04 [INFO] [my-website.com] acme: Trying renewal with 1428 hours remaining
2022/10/01 00:00:04 [INFO] [my-website.com, www.my-website.com] acme: Obtaining bundled SAN certificate
2022/10/01 00:00:04 acme: error: 0 :: POST :: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-order :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:rateLimited :: Service busy; retry later.
Started nginx
Stopped nginx
2022/11/01 00:00:04 [INFO] [my-website.com] acme: Trying renewal with 684 hours remaining
2022/11/01 00:00:04 [INFO] [my-website.com, www.my-website.com] acme: Obtaining bundled SAN certificate
2022/11/01 00:00:04 failed to post JWS message: failed to sign content: failed to sign content: square/go-jose: Error generating nonce: failed to get nonce from HTTP HEAD: 503 ::HEAD :: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-nonce :: unexpected end of JSON input :: 
Started nginx
Stopped nginx
2022/11/30 09:57:10 [INFO] [my-website.com] acme: Trying renewal with -21 hours remaining
2022/11/30 09:57:10 [INFO] [my-website.com, www.my-website.com] acme: Obtaining bundled SAN certificate
2022/11/30 09:57:11 [INFO] [my-website.com] AuthURL: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/182217855127
2022/11/30 09:57:11 [INFO] [www.my-website.com] AuthURL: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/182217855137
2022/11/30 09:57:11 [INFO] [my-website.com] acme: use tls-alpn-01 solver
2022/11/30 09:57:11 [INFO] [www.my-website.com] acme: use tls-alpn-01 solver
2022/11/30 09:57:11 [INFO] [my-website.com] acme: Trying to solve TLS-ALPN-01
2022/11/30 09:57:16 [INFO] [my-website.com] The server validated our request
2022/11/30 09:57:16 [INFO] [www.my-website.com] acme: Trying to solve TLS-ALPN-01
2022/11/30 09:57:23 [INFO] [www.my-website.com] The server validated our request
2022/11/30 09:57:23 [INFO] [my-website.com, www.my-website.com] acme: Validations succeeded; requesting certificates
2022/11/30 09:57:23 [INFO] [my-website.com] Server responded with a certificate.
Started nginx
```

on 2022-11-30 I had to execute below command on shell manually. It worked well.

```
# /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/scripts/renew-certificate.sh >> /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/scripts/log-crontab_renew_certificate_sh-220531 2>&1
```

Why It doesn't work with crontab?